# Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to type 'NSString' in coercion

Tags: swift, xcode, nsstring

Im trying to make this calculator for various math formulas and I'm stuck at this point. I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-_74lanSnL8)

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class pythagorasViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var aLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var bLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var aField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var bField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var a = (aField.text as NSString).floatValue
    var b = (bField.text as NSString).floatValue
    var answer = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    answerLabel.text = "\(answer)"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

The part where I'm getting the error is at:

```
var a = (aField.text as NSString).floatValue
var b = (bField.text as NSString).floatValue
```

Comment: Why use `NSString` at all? Swift has `String`. And it's much better to use `NSNumberFormatter` to try to convert user-entered numbers into actual numbers.

Comment: And you need to deal with the user entering values that are not valid.

Comment: There are so many tutorials with so much smattering...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer let to var when possible.  You do not need to use NSString.  You can cast String to Float?.  You need to unwrap both the text property which is a String? (if you have a question about the type of a variable option click and it will show you) and the Float? conversion:

```
func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    guard let aText = aField.text,
          let bText = bField.text,
          let a = Float(aText),
          let b = Float(bText) else {
        return
    }
    let answer = sqrt(a*a + b*b)
    answerLabel.text = "\(answer)"
}
```

Comment: There's no casting in your code. `Float(aText)` is not a cast, it's a conversion. Significant difference.